# How to add text lines to file if doesn't exit

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu-16.04

I need to add multiple text lines to a file only if they don't exist.

It's for configuration files automation purposes.

For example:

I've this file:

```
Option 1
Option 2
Option 3
   - some suboption b
Option 4
```

And I've the following entire text to append (not as single lines) because it's posible that one of these lines are already added in another Option and for that reason, the line is going to be bypassed which is not the desired behavior.

Notice if we add lines one by one and not as the entire text, the line **- some suboption b** will be omitted because it already exists as a suboption of **Option 5**

```
Option 5
   - some suboption a
   - some suboption b
   - some suboption c
   - some suboption d
```

I've tried to use sed and awk but it doesn't as an entire text but line per line.

After run the needed command or shell script, i expect the following file.

```
Option 1
Option 2
Option 3
   - some suboption b
Option 4
Option 5
   - some suboption a
   - some suboption b
   - some suboption c
   - some suboption d
```

Comment: This question is a bit confusing. Despite the long description in the question about options and suboptions, based on the example, it looks like you're just appending the second block of text to the first block of text. If it's supposed to be more complex than this, could you place a more complex example in the question?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow Juan. You question has a nice attempt to explain the problem, but it would be much simpler to others if you show some real instances of sample input and output. That’s because its pretty hard to analyse how suboptions are to be differentiated and what is the source of input.

Answer (score 1):

You want to append that Option 5 block to the end of a file if it's not already present? Maybe something like

```sh
if ! grep -q '^Option 5$' yourfile; then
    cat <<EOF >>yourfile
Option 5
   - some suboption a
   - some suboption b
   - some suboption c
   - some suboption d
EOF
fi
```